# How can I seal off the liquid line on a sankey keg to allow force carbonation?

Tags: carbonation, keg

I want to carbonate several sankey kegs, but the keg couplers have the liquid line open, so if I apply CO2 to them, the beer will come out if I don't have a serving line connected, I only have 2 serving lines, but I want to carbonate all 6 sankey kegs at the same time, how can I block that line? or is there another thing I need to buy/get to close that line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to stop the flow out of that end of the coupler.  Pretty much anything you dream up that will connect with 7/8" 14 thread will work.  If you have a local fitting place, ask for a cap nut, or acorn nut with that threading and you will be good to go.  A search on eBay for "7/8 14 nut" had a few that fit the bill for under $5.

A note of safety: If you just cap the end of the coupler, be sure to bleed out the pressure before taking off the nut.  The CO2 in solution will remain, and you wont have a projectile coming for you when you take off the cap.  Also some Teflon tape will ensure a good fit and will stop the nut from seizing to the coupler

If you want something more commercial, and can pony up some money, there are a series of ball valves that are made to do exactly what you are looking for:

http://www.kegs.com/products/shut-off-ball-valve/

Comment: Nice answer.  +1 for the link, and for not suggesting Teflon tape will help the seal :)